# IMAP PHP GMAIL - move email

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap, move

Please may be sone one can answer my question
I move the email - but on GMAIL account message is not moved to FOLDER\LABEL.

```
foreach ($mailboxIds as $id) {

            $imapConnection = $this->createImapConnection('');
            $mailbox = new MailboxComponent($imapConnection);
            $stream = $mailbox->getImapStream();

            $email = MailboxEmails::findOne($id);
            if (!$email)
                throw new NotFoundHttpException();

            $result = imap_mail_copy($stream, $email->number_id, $folder->name, CP_UID);
            $uid = imap_uid($stream, $email->number_id);
            $email->folder_id = $folder->id;
            $email->number_id = $uid;
            $email->save();
            imap_expunge($stream);
            imap_close($stream);
        }
```

So no error, all is ok, $email->number_id - its the order number in folder.

Comment: Don't use sequence numbers.  Use UIDs. You are copying using UID but supplying a sequence number.

Comment: bug how from IMAP to get it ?